# Shutdown AWS VM on a schedule - but with a warning to the user if someone is logged in

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

Is there a way to simply stop an AWS VM (Windows server) instance on a schedule time? I am looking for a simple solution where I can set this in the console rather than create a whole solution using AWS Instance Scheduler.

I also require a way for a prompt to be displayed to the user if someone is logged into the VM at that time and he could either confirm to let the shut down process continue or cancel the process.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try two scenario for this use case :

1. Try AWS EC2 System Manager Run Command and schedule a custom PowerShell script.

   - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-ec2-run-command-remote-instance-management-at-scale/
2. Try to use the new Scheduled AWS Lambda with PowerShell Core.

   - https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/09/aws-lambda-supports-powershell-core/

For the PS script, you can inspire you from this one :

- https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Custom-PowerShell-GUI-7c7fbda8

Answer (score 0):

I would go to CloudWatch and create a new Event Rule, based on:

- Event Source: Schedule with Cron expression
- Target: SSM Run Command

  - Document: "AWS-RunPowerShellScript"
  - Target key: InstanceIds
  - Target value(s): your-instance-id
  - Parameters, Commands: `shutdown /s /t 300 /c 'Your computer will shutdown soon. If you want to cancel it, please run the following command: shutdown /a'`

You will need to ensure your instance is enrolled on SSM following [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-configuring-access-role.html). The shutdown command will wait 5 minutes for shutdown and it will send a message to the user.